# Mysql2::Error: Invalid default value for 'column_name'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Hey I have a rails scheme and I've tried to create a database in mysql .I want to realod the database from scheme with this command:

```
rails db:schema:load
```

other tables are created successfully but this table which has default values have problem:

```
create_table "settings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "legal_columns_order",     default: "id,indicator,classification,urgency,package,registrar,subset_type,creation_time,sender,conjunctions,followings,responses,letter_receivers,letter_date,subject,letter_number,description,recipient,receiving_type,person_name,tel_number,portal_number,operator,transcriptions"
    t.string   "legal_columns_active",    default: "true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true"
    t.string   "official_columns_order",  default: "id,indicator,classification,urgency,recipient,package,creation_time,sender,registrar,subset_type,conjunctions,followings,responses,letter_receivers,letter_date,subject,letter_number,barcode,description,receiving_type,transcriptions"
    t.string   "official_columns_active", default: "true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true"
    t.string   "panel_column_order",      default: "{\"panel_1\":[\"letterType\",\"subject\",\"subjectSugestion\",\"letterNumber\",\"classification\",\"sender\",\"urgency\",\"receivers\",\"letterDate\"],\"panel_2\":[\"recipient\",\"recivingType\",\"creation_time\",\"Packageid\",\"barcode\",\"Scan\"],\"panel_3\":[\"following\",\"conjunction\",\"response\",\"transcriptions\",\"description\",\"enclosed\",\"person_name\",\"tel_number\",\"portal_number\",\"operator\"],\"panel_names\":{\"panel_1\":\"اطلاعات اصلی\",\"panel_2\":\"اطلاعات ثبتی\",\"panel_3\":\"اطلاعات تکمیلی\"}}"
    t.string   "package_panel_columns",   default: "{\"panel_1\":[\"courier_company\",\"classification\",\"receiving_type\",\"courier_type\",\"first_barcode\",\"second_barcode\",\"post_receiving_date\",\"creation_time\",\"registrar\"],\"panel_2\":[\"sender\",\"letter_receivers\",\"recipient_unit\",\"export_date\",\"subject\",\"recipient\",\"description\"],\"panel_names\":{\"panel_1\":\"اطلاعات اصلی\",\"panel_2\":\"اطلاعات ثبتی\"}}"
    t.string   "package_columns_order",   default: "id,courier_company,classification,registrar,post_receiving_date,receiving_type,courier_type,first_barcode,sender,letter_receivers,export_date,subject,recipient,description,creation_time,recipient_unit"
    t.string   "package_columns_active",  default: "true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true"
    t.string   "form_panel_columns",      default: "{\"panel_1\":[\"formType\",\"sender\",\"subject\",\"receivers\",\"creationDate\",\"receptionDate\",\"registrar\"],\"panel_2\":[\"recipient\",\"recipient_unit\",\"attachments\",\"documentNumber\",\"deliveryDate\",\"description\"],\"panel_names\":{\"panel_1\":\"اطلاعات اصلی\",\"panel_2\":\"اطلاعات تکمیلی\"}}"
    t.string   "form_columns_order",      default: "id,form_type,sender,subject,registrar,form_receivers,creation_date,reception_date,recipient,document_number,delivery_date,description,recipient_unit"
    t.string   "form_columns_active",     default: "true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true"
    t.string   "tracking_column_order",   default: "registrar,package,classification,indicator,letter_urgency,sender,subset_type,letter_created_at,assignee,paraph,tracking_type,tracking_urgency,tracking_created_at"
    t.string   "tracking_column_active",  default: "true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_settings_on_user_id"
  end
```

I've got this error :

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Invalid default value for 'legal_columns_order': CREATE TABLE `settings`
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.string` creates a `VARCHAR(255)` column with a maximum length of `255` characters. But your default is `269` characters long. See [`NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L36) in Rails' source code:

```
  NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES = {
    primary_key: "bigint auto_increment PRIMARY KEY",
    string:      { name: "varchar", limit: 255 },
    text:        { name: "text", limit: 65535 },
    integer:     { name: "int", limit: 4 },
    float:       { name: "float" },
    decimal:     { name: "decimal" },
    datetime:    { name: "datetime" },
    timestamp:   { name: "timestamp" },
    time:        { name: "time" },
    date:        { name: "date" },
    binary:      { name: "blob", limit: 65535 },
    boolean:     { name: "tinyint", limit: 1 },
    json:        { name: "json" },
  }
```

First of all, you have to investigate if a limit of `255` characters is feasible in the context of your application. It doesn't look like but perhaps using shorter defaults is an option.

When you need to store longer texts you have two options:

1. Use `t.text` instead of `t.string` that support longer texts (defaults to `65535` but can be configured to store MBs of data). But unfortunately, this data type doesn't support defaults ([*BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values.*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)). You would have to set the default in your model instead.
2. Or you manually set a higher limit - for example 2048 chars (choose wisely) - on that column:

   ```
   t.string "legal_columns_order", limit: 2_048, default: ...
   ```

I would suggest using a `TEXT` column type and to handle the defaults in your application because that makes it much easier when the default text change later on.

To handle defaults in a model, I would do something like this:

```
after_initialize :set_defaults

private 
def set_defaults
  self.legal_columns_order  ||= "id,indicator,classification,urgency,package,registrar,subset_type,creation_time,sender,conjunctions,followings,responses,letter_receivers,letter_date,subject,letter_number,description,recipient,receiving_type,person_name,tel_number,portal_number,operator,transcriptions"
  self.legal_columns_active ||= "true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true"
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I did this but again this error : Mysql2::Error: BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'legal_columns_order' can't have a default value

Comment: @AfsaneFadaei You are right. I missed that MySQL doesn't support defaults on TEXT columns. I updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the maximum length size for a string field is 255 characters and those are 269. Move from string to text.

Comment: I did this and got this error : Mysql2::Error: BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'legal_columns_order' can't have a default value

Comment: Ok, so text can't have a default value :D

Comment: so what can I do ?

Comment: Manage it in the application layer. I know, it's not cool like default value, but I don't think there is another lean way